# Font Awesome Icon in PHP File

Tags: php, font-awesome

I'd like to replace the "Play Video" text that's being pulled with the font awesome play icon.

```
$media .= '<a href="#video-popup-'.$post->ID.'" class="pretty_photo default-link">'.__("Play Video", NECTAR_THEME_NAME).' </a> ';
```

This is what I tried:

```
$media .= '<a href="#video-popup-'.$post->ID.'" class="pretty_photo default-link">'.__("<i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>", NECTAR_THEME_NAME).' </a> ';
```

But to no avail. This is how it looks in the overall function:

```
if( !empty($video_embed) || !empty($video_m4v) ) {

                        if( !empty( $video_embed ) && floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) < "3.6" ) { 

                            $media .= '<a href="#video-popup-'.$post->ID.'" class="pretty_photo default-link">'.__("Play Video", NECTAR_THEME_NAME).' </a> ';
                            $media .= '<div id="video-popup-'.$post->ID.'">';
                            $media .= '<div class="video-wrap">' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($video_embed)) . '</div>';
                            $media .= '</div>';
                        } 

                        else {
                             $media .= '<a href="'.get_template_directory_uri(). '/includes/portfolio-functions/video.php?post-id=' .$post->ID.'&iframe=true&width=854" class="pretty_photo default-link" >'.__("Play Video", NECTAR_THEME_NAME).'</a> ';    
                         } 

                    }
```

Any help you can give would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: Show your final code here just to check how you have placed it in PHP?

Comment: Just added in edited OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should put the icon inside the double underscore function (`__()`) since I believe that is just for text for translation purposes. Plus it might just strip out html. So try this instead:

```
$media .= '<a href="#video-popup-'.$post->ID.'" class="pretty_photo default-link"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> ';
```

Here is a reference on the double underscore function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2